# What are the 'corner cases' in differing markdown implementations?

Tags: javascript, perl, markdown

The author writes the following about the differences between different markdown implementations:

> The result is that there are a lot of Markdown parsers in a lot of languages, and they all give slightly different results in a lot of corner cases (and a lot of not-so-corner cases). The best I could do in Clojure is pick one implementation and try my best to match it.
>   http://briancarper.net/blog/415/

My question is - what are these 'corner cases'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nicest way to analyse such corner cases in Markdown parsing is John MacFarlane's [Babelmark 2](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/): You enter some Markdown code and it shows you all the output differences between all the Markdown renderers it knows about.

Answer (score 0):

If we say the major implementations are [John Gruber's original](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), and the subsequent [showdown.js](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown/blob/master/src/showdown.js) implementation - which now [appears to be the one people use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307480/what-is-the-canonical-implementation-of-markdown/7308574#7308574) - then the list of corner cases is [here](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown#readme).

---

Edit - it appears that [showdown.js has bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343796/markdown-showdown-bug-in-detab-regex) - and [you should look at pagedown.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343796/markdown-showdown-bug-in-detab-regex/7346173#7346173)  as the one they use on stackoverflow.