# Markdown -> Showdown bug in detab regex?

Tags: javascript, perl, markdown

I'm looking at Gruber's original Markdown implementation [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and the Showdown implementation [here](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown/blob/master/src/showdown.js).

I'm comparing the `_Detab` function in each. I'm giving each the following string

```
"Where\tis pancakes house?"
```

The Perl version of the test and output is [here](http://ideone.com/VhAAF). This is `26` characters long.

The JavaScript version of the test and output is [here](http://ideone.com/glp1E). This is `27` characters long.

```
      123456789012345678901234567
Perl: Where   is pancakes house?
  JS: Where    is pancakes house?
```

Have I made a mistake? Is it a bug, or is there some other purpose?

Comment: +1: Nice question! (Though I wouldn't have +1'd it had cjm not edited the actual output into the question...)

Comment: I like how the JS code says "In perl we could fix it by anchoring the regexp with \G", and then the Perl code doesn't so this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several bugs in Showdown's detabber. That's why for Stack Overflow's version, [I have rewritten it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77552/please-make-table-previews-match-actual-output/90548#90548):

```
function _Detab(text) {
    if (!/\t/.test(text))
        return text;

    var spaces = ["    ", "   ", "  ", " "],
    skew = 0,
    v;

    return text.replace(/[\n\t]/g, function (match, offset) {
        if (match === "\n") {
            skew = offset + 1;
            return match;
        }
        v = (offset - skew) % 4;
        skew = offset + 1;
        return spaces[v];
    });
}
```

It detabs correctly, and if I recall my measurements correctly, this is about as fast (maybe a little slower) as the original in older IE versions, and *much* faster in newer browsers.

See http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown for our full version of Showdown.

Comment: Thanks @balpha. Could I just confirm what you mean by 'detabs correctly'. Are you saying you're closer to John Gruber's perl implementation - or that your implementation is better suited to the broader problem of removing tabs?

Comment: As I said in the Meta post, "replacing tabs by one to four spaces such that the following character ends up in a column that's a multiple of four", in other words, just what you expect a detabber to do. As I see it, that's exactly what Gruber's version does (but Perl RegExps aren't exactly my area of expertise). The main difference is that the Perl version allows configuring the width of a tab, while here it's hardcoded to four. This is true of all of Showdown, though.

Comment: The main issue with Showdown's original detabber is that it ignores line breaks -- it counts characters from the beginning of the whole string, not the beginning of the current line. Unless your previous lines sum up to a character count that's divisible by four, this is bound to fail.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug in the Showdown implementation.  Markdown uses 4-space tabs, so a string ending in a tab should always be a multiple of 4 characters long after tabs are converted to spaces.  The Perl version makes `"Where\t"` 8 characters, but the JavaScript one makes it 9 characters.

I suspect the bug may not occur with tabs at the beginning of a line, which is how they're normally used in Markdown, which would explain why it hasn't been noticed.